# Changing the Direction of a Photon

Tags: visible-light, photons, scattering

I know that a photon can change its direction of travel when it is absorbed by an atom and then randomly re-emitted. However, by what mechanism does a photon change its direction of travel when it gets *scattered* by an atom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism is exactly the same.   The only difference between absorption/re-emission and scattering is that something interferes with the atom in the case of absorption/re-emission, so that the phase relationship between incoming and outgoing photon is lost.  In scattering it is maintained.  A consequence is that the possible directions of propagation is different in the two cases.  For scattering, the photon excites a dipole polarization, so the radiation pattern is that of dipole radiation:  peaked in the plane perpendicular to the polarization of the photon.  In absorption, the dipole polarization is disturbed; the outgoing photon can go in any direction.

Comment: My understanding of scattering is that a photon induces dipole radiation in an atom. But what happens to the original photon?

Comment: There is more than one way to look at this.  One way:  the original photon is annihilated when the polarization is induced, and a new photon created when the polarization is destroyed.